# Upgrade Site collection to 15 in SharePoint 2013 Failed

Tags: 2013, upgrade, variations

The site collection contains 5 languages variations (English, French, German, Dutch and Portuguese). The site has been migrated from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 using the standard Microsoft migration (Backup DataBase and mount the database on Sharepoint 2013). The Site use Nintex workflow and has been migrated in the same time as the SharePoint Content database. The site run now on 14 but when we want to upgrade it to 15, we have an

> Error on upgrade: Exception: Invalid field name. {8484dbaf-e6d2-4f98-9aa7-e19f89260224}.

This error occurs every time we want to use the variation label.

After investigation we found that 2 fields don’t add on the upgrade process:

- IsMachineTranslationEnabledFieldName
- IsHumanTranslationEnabledFieldName

> 09/16/2014 16:17:48.46 UpgradeSpSite.vshost (0x2E58)   0x2B08  SharePoint Foundation Upgrade   SPWebWssSequence2   ajy85   ERROR   Feature upgrade incomplete for Feature 'Publishing' (Id: 15/'22a9ef51-737b-4ff2-9346-694633fe4416') in Web 'http://test.site.com'. Exception: Invalid field name. {8484dbaf-e6d2-4f98-9aa7-e19f89260224}  /sites/demo/Variation Labels  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

We have opened a case to microsoft but if someone has the solution it will be good?

Comment: I tried this one and it worked for me. http://blog.konffaaja.com/2015/08/23/variations-does-not-work-after-db-attach-upgrade-from-2010-to-2013/

Answer (score 0):

Go to the hidden Variation Labels List (probably has a translated name) before the upgrade and make sure the name is "Variation Labels" and not a translated name in French, German, Dutch or Portuguese.