# Site Upgrade from SharePoint 2010 to 2013 Fails

Tags: migration, upgrade-sharepoint

Im having the same issue reported in this question
[Upgrade Site collection to 15 in SharePoint 2013 Failed](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116373/upgrade-site-collection-to-15-in-sharepoint-2013-failed/282730#282730)

After the process of Mounting the content dabase, everythins was working fine, but when I tried to the visual upgrade, i get errors on the subsites
Feature upgrade action 'CustomUpgradeAction.EnsureVariationsInfrastructure' threw an exception upgrading Feature 'Publishing' (Id: 15/'22a9ef51-737b-4ff2-9346-694633fe4416') in Web xxxxxxxxx
Exception: Invalid field name. {8484dbaf-e6d2-4f98-9aa7-e19f89260224}  /Variation Labels    0304649f-8ac5-a0ef-52b4-0d9dee0f3098

Has anyone been with this error.

On this SharePoint 2013 farm, I already upgrade another web application, coming from the same SP2010 Env, also with variations configured and with no problems.

Comment: Did you install any required language packs? Did you execute Test-SPContentDatabase to verify possible errors? Also, make sure the database transaction log is not full and has enough free space.

Comment: Language packs installed, and the vm has enough disk space, i even put the transaction log to the database to simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved, after setting the VerboseEx loglevel, it showed an error not finding the "Variations Label" list, it was searching the name in portuguese.
"Translation.Provisioner.AddVariationTransactionColumns Site does not contain Variations Labels List. List "Etiquetas de Variação" does not exist.

Changed the locale to en-us on the site collection, started a new upgrade and everything worked ok.